# How to access a queue element based on index

Tags: python, performance

I have a queue

```
from collections import deque
queue = deque([(1, 2), (5, 7), (3, 9)])
```

**and give a index.**

My function as following:

```
def iterQue(que, index):
    data = []
    for d in que:
        data.append(d[index])
    return data
```

**Output:**

`index = 0, get [1, 5, 3]`

`index = 1, get [2, 7, 9]`

Is there any better way to modify my function ?

Comment: why not transform you data with `zip()`? Also can you give more context on why you're using a `deque`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands The data structure that others gave me is a queue....

Comment: You can actually just use `zip` as suggested above @vincentlai ! Check my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
from collections import deque
queue = deque([(1, 2), (5, 7), (3, 9)])

li = [[] for _ in range(2)]

for item in queue:
    for i in range(2):
        li[i].append(item[i])

print(li)

for idx, item in enumerate(li):
    print('index = {}, get {}'.format(idx, item))
```

Or as suggested in the comment below by Tobias (Thanks @tobias_k)

```
from collections import deque
queue = deque([(1, 2), (5, 7), (3, 9)])

li = [ list(item) for item in zip(*queue)]
print(li)

for idx, item in enumerate(li):
    print('index = {}, get {}'.format(idx, item))
```

The output will look like as follows in both cases

```
[[1, 5, 3], [2, 7, 9]]

index = 0, get [1, 5, 3]
index = 1, get [2, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Which is a rather complicated way of doing `li = list(zip(*queue))`.

Comment: Thank you @tobias_k , I am relatively new to Python, and still learning on how to simplify code by using builtins like `zip`, Anyhow I updated my answer to note your comment! Hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your function to use a list comprehension like so:

```
def iterQue(que, index):
    return [n[index] for n in que]
```

In this case it should be more efficient, if you are sure that the queue doesn't change after the `iterQue` call you could return a generator instead of a list, just change `[n[index] for n in que]` to `(n[index] for n in que)`.